# gstreamer images to video in real-time

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to use gstreamer to save images into a video format in real time as they are 
being captured.  I have the command to save the images.  This line is:

```
gst-launch -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! jpegdec ! timeoverlay halign=right valign=bottom ! clockoverlay halign=left valign=bottom time-format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" ! tee name=t ! queue ! sdlvideosink t. ! queue ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=1/1" ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location="./Desktop/frames/frame%06d.jpg"
```

This command saves the images to a folder.  I wrote another command that takes those pictures and saves them to a video.  This command is:

```
gst-launch -e multifilesrc location=./Desktop/frames/frame%06d.jpg ! image/jpeg,framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv ! progressreport name=progress ! avimux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

I need a way of combining these two commands so that the video can be saved in real time.  I cannot seem to figure out how this is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I took away the multifilesink element from your first line and added avimux and filesink to your second line (and formatted it better for this forum) to produce this:

```
gst-launch -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
'image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! \
jpegdec ! timeoverlay halign=right valign=bottom ! \
clockoverlay halign=left valign=bottom time-format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" ! \
tee name=t ! \
queue ! \
sdlvideosink t. ! \
queue ! \
videorate ! \
capsfilter caps="video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=1/1" ! \
ffmpegcolorspace ! \
jpegenc ! \
avimux ! \
filesink location=test.avi
```

Not sure if it will work, and it also discards the progressreport component (not sure how it works). If the command line fails, please post the gst-launch console error messages.